# How do you use the plural method in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've been puzzling over the `plural` functionality in Rust's `std::fmt` module, but I need a concrete example to make it real.

The 0.9 documentation for it is half way down the page here: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/std/fmt/index.html

Is this intended to be useful to pluralize words?  For example, how would I use it to print:

```
This page has been visited 0 times.
This page has been visited 1 time.
This page has been visited 2 times.
```

I tried this, but I'm getting an error:

```
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;
    let s1 = format!("This page has been visited {:d} {0, plural, one{time} other{times}}.", count);
    println(s1);
}

error: argument used to format with `d` was attempted to not be used for formatting
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, the `plural` and `select` methods have since been removed in [#14831](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/14831)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite confusing, but apparently you can not use the same parameter for both format strings. That is, you can not use the parameter 0 (`count`) for both `{:d}` and `{0, plural, one{time} other{times}}`.

It is possible to work around this limitation by passing the parameter twice in the function:

```
let s1 = format!("This page has been visited {:d} {1, plural, one{time} other{times}}.", count, count);
```

Alternatively you can use `#` to put the value itself inside the `plural` formatting:

```
let s1 = format!("This page has been visited {0, plural, one{# time} other{# times}}.", count);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! But it looks like this only works with `uint` types. The second option works as written, but only for uint, not for int. The first option does not work because the `{:d}` is for signed types.  Can `plural` be made to work with signed numbers?